# Wifi slow with new router

Tags: ubuntu, firefox, wireless-router

I recently acquired a Netgear WNR1000-100NAS to replace my old router. Computer is running Ubuntu 14.04 and Firefox is my browser.

When I set up my new router, pages hesitate for several seconds before finally loading in my browser. I figured the issue was with a Firefox update since everything loads quickly in Chromium. I've also toggled settings for the wireless router like disabling 20/40 MHz coexistence, using 8.8.8.8 and 8.8.4.4 as a nameserver instead of my ISP (Comcast). When my computer is wired to the internet, the issue remains. My smart televisions have no issue streaming NetFlix. When I'm on a loaded page, there is no issue with loading times.

Over the weekend, I was out of state at a friend's house using their wifi on my computer. Web pages loaded fast, as they oughta with broadband, in Firefox much to my surprise.

I'm stumped as to how to fix this issue.

Comment: The downvote makes no sense to me.

Comment: Have you tried these recommendations? http://itsfoss.com/speed-up-slow-wifi-connection-ubuntu/  As of now, we are kinda short on data input. But let us know whether any of this helps.

Comment: Or you may try following this recommendation, http://www.systutorials.com/3767/smaller-mtu-faster-wifi-linux/

Comment: @heptapod I would suggest backing up firefox and possibly resetting to default to see if that makes a difference.  If it's tied to Firefox, it's going to be something that's difficult to find, so resetting is a start.  If it still doesn't work, you may want to see if there's any packet loss or any trouble with a browser besides chromium if you can.  I would also double check if updating the router's firmware or resetting to default doesn't make a difference either.  It's a pain, but just remember to test in-between steps so you know where the problem is.

Comment: Can you simply try running a test at [SpeedTest.net](http://speedtest.net) _if you can get the page to load_? If this test shows that you have decent bandwidth, the issue might be with actually resolving the connections at the router rather then the WiFi itself; while we are at it, I guess you can try running one at [PingTest.net](http://pingtest.net) too.